# Save all hbase table names to the bash array

Tags: bash, sed, hbase, hbase-shell

I would like to store the names of all my hbase tables in an array inside my bash script.

1. All `sed` hotfixes are acceptable.
2. All better solutions (like `readarray` it from some zookeeper file I am not aware of) are acceptable

I have two hbase tables called `MY_TABLE_NAME_1` and `MY_TABLE_NAME_2`, so what I want would be:

```
tables = (
  MY_TABLE_NAME_1
  MY_TABLE_NAME_2
)
```

---

What I tried:

Basing on [HBase Shell in OS Scripts by Cloudera](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.2.4/book/hbase.shell.noninteractive.html):

```
echo "list" | /path/to/hbase/bin/hbase shell -n > /home/me/hbase-tables
readarray -t tables < /home/me/hbase-tables
```

but inside my `/home/me/hbase-tables` is:

```
MY_TABLE_NAME_1
MY_TABLE_NAME_2
2 row(s) in 0.3310 seconds

MY_TABLE_NAME_1
MY_TABLE_NAME_2
```

Comment: Why are the names duplicated?

Comment: Amount of the names is unknown, as well as the names themselves. So they might be `MY_TABLE_NAME_1`, `MY_TABLE_NAME_2` as well as `banana`, `cucumber` and `tomato`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem is that 1) you've got the "x row(s) in x.xxx seconds" message and 2) the table names are duplicated ? Anyway I guess you might have a `--quiet` or similar flag on your `hbase shell` tool that might fix these two problems at once. (edit : that should be the `-n` flag for `--non-interactive`, but you're already using it... not sure this tool is well made for returning parseable output)

Comment: Supposing deleting everything until the "x row(s) in x.xxx seconds" works for you, you could fix the file with GNU `sed '0,/[0-9]* row/d'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `readarray`/`mapfile` just fine. But to remove duplicates/skip empty lines and remove unnecessary strings, you need a filter using `awk`.

Also you don't need to create a temporary file and then parse that file, but directly use a technique called process substitution which allows the output of a command be available as if it is available in a temporary file

```
mapfile -t output < <(echo "list" | /path/to/hbase/bin/hbase shell -n | awk '!unique[$0]++ && !/seconds/ && NF')
```

Now the array would contain only the unique table names from the `hbase` output. That said, you should really look-up for the solution to remove the noise as part of the query output than post-process it this way.